# Using Pi to bridge two networks through SSH tunnel

Tags: networking, ssh

TLDR: How to route SQL traffic through a reverse VPN tunnel on a Win10 client to an outside network.

I'm hoping I can get some clear advice / tips on this desired setup.  I'm looking to access an MS SQL server on a clients network.  A VPN solution seems a bit over the top for what I need.

I'm trying to establish a route for traffic from my Win10 system at home to a network with a Pi connected at one of the offices.  The Pi will be connected by eth0 to the network I need access to.  I can either use the same connection to reach the outside world or use WiFi to connect to a separate network at the location that just provides internet and use that for the tunnel.

I can enable inbound access at home and successfully SSH into the network but I don't have inbound control at my clients location.  I'd like to setup a tunnel from the Pi to Home where I can then route traffic from Win10 at home to the clients network.

At home I'm using the 172.16.0.1/24 subnet and the client uses 192.168.0.1/24.  The setup I'm after is SSHing to my Win10 system at home from the client on my Pi and then having SQL bound traffic from home on port 1433 routed to an IP in the clients subnet sent through the SSH tunnel.

I'm reasonably comfortable in the terminal but networking isn't my first language.  I'm hoping somebody would be kind enough to help advise with the actual steps, tools and commands I need to do this.  I've had look into some options and getting a little lost especially with the Windows setup side of things and how to actually configure routes etc.

Comment: With MS Window$ we cannot help you much.